# override file_field in ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In ruby on rails project, I use file_field for upload an image by user.

I use below code in my project:

```
<%= form_for@problem, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field :photo %>
<% end %>
```

by this code when user click on button that created by rails, user can select image and save it to "photo".

now I want override this, that when user click on "choose file", rails run below HTTP request instead of open "choose file window":

```
require 'net/http'
result = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/1607/ruby_on_rails/256/ror_folder_256_v3.png'))
```

How can I override this?

Or how can I run this http request and get photo of this url and save it to photo? (photo is create by paperclip for problem's controller.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do much in the way of manipulating the file input field for security reasons. I'd just make an invisible div positioned over it and trigger a Javascript event to make a request. Make sense?

Comment: I don't have any idea about use javascript event to make the request.
Can I use another rails syntax to run this request and save the response into photo?

Comment: Since you're using paperclip, can you specify this as the default image? I'm not exactly sure what is is you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: The url is static for each user, but the image of the url is change every 1 minute. Because of this, I cannot use this image as defult. I want make a button that when user click on this button, the image of url save into photo in paperclip.

Comment: Why don't you create a helper method that points to the link and use that as the default image?

Comment: I'm new in rails, Can you guidance me how do this?